# .load content when checkbox checked, remove when unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have a number of checkboxes which, when checked invoke the below script to show a chunk of html inside a form using `.load`:

```
$('input.article').click(function(){
        var bits = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var id = bits[1];
        var article = 'article_' + id + '.html';
        $('#form_' + id).load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/html/' + article);
        $('#form_' + id).toggle();
        $('.submit').show();
    });
```

The forms are dynamically created in the view like so:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++){ ?>
        <div id="form_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="hide">
       </div>
<?php } ?>
```

However, I need the loaded html to be removed whenever the checkbox is *unchecked*, and that's where I get stuck. Using `.toggle()`the html is hidden, but it is being submitted anyway. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Any HTML please? To check if the checkbox is checked, use `is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('input.article').click(function(){
        var bits = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var id = bits[1];
        var article = 'article_' + id + '.html';
        if(this.checked){
          $('#form_' + id).load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/html/' + product);
        }
        else{
          $('#form_' + id).empty();  
        }
        $('.submit').show();
});
```

Comment: Well that was easy! Problem solved! I was trying `if($(this)+':checked')){`which obviously wasn't the right approach... Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

So add a check to see if it is checked. If it is not, empty its contents and hide it.

```
var bits = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
var id = bits[1];
if (this.checked) {
    //...get content
} else {
    $('#form_' + id).empty().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only load the content if the container is empty, and toggle the container based on wether or not the checkbox is checked :

```
$('input.article').on('change', function(){
    var id      = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0],
        article = 'article_' + id + '.html',
        form    = $('#form_' + id);

    if (form.is(':empty'))
        form.load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/html/' + article);

    form.toggle(this.checked);
    $('.submit').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @adeneo. Your solution is somewhat similar to the one pXL provided. Which of both solutions would be most effective?